# Solutions to a "Lambert's problem in velocity"

Tags: orbital-mechanics

[Lambert's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_problem) (also [here](http://ccar.colorado.edu/asen5050/ASEN5050/Lectures_files/lecture16.pdf) and [here](http://ccar.colorado.edu/imd/2015/documents/LambertHandout.pdf)):

$$\mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{r_2}, t \rightarrow \mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}$$

was solved by [Johann Heinrich Lambert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Heinrich_Lambert) [image: Lambert] via Lambert's Theorem (see references below).

I'm wondering if there exists in the literature a (solved) problem where the given parameters are

$$\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{v_2}, t \rightarrow \mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{r_2}$$

$$\text{or}$$

$$\mathbf{v_1}, \mathbf{r_2}, t \rightarrow \mathbf{r_1}, \mathbf{v_2}$$

where $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are position and velocity vectors.

---

For the second case, [this shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/ltlfWB) gives (if I didn't mess up the math) the locus of $\mathbf{r_1}$ for all the $t$ with a given $\mathbf{v_1} = (1,0,0)$ and a varying $\mathbf{r_2}$ (the red cross).

---

Helpful references for Lambert's Theorem:

- NASA technical note [A Unified Form of Lambert's Theorem](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19690027552.pdf)
- Erich Weissstein's World of Physics [Lambert's Theorem](http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/physics/LambertsTheorem.html)
- James F. Jordan, 1964, JPL Technical Report 32-521 [The Application of Lambert’s Theorem to the Solution of Interplanetary Transfer Problems](http://www.gravityassist.com/IAF1/Ref.%201-77.pdf)

---

Comment: I have to concur with the previous comment. What is your question? Else, this sounds like a classical mechanics problem, possibly homework. You want to minimise the time t between P1 and P2 under the action of a gravitational potential? Look up the brahystochrone-problem.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape ditto. Just because someone uses formal language to pose a question doesn't mean it's a homework problem. You might consider the possibility that the OP *is someone who writes homework problems!*

Comment: @ BenoitLebeaupin the Shadertoy link does not seem to work for me and at least some users - maybe it needs to be made public so non-registered users can see it?

Comment: Sorry for the broken link, does it work better now?

Comment: And no, it's not for homework, I just became interested in orbital mechanics after playing Kerbal Space Program, as well as how GPU could be used to do calculations.

Comment: @BenoitLebeaupin yep the link works fine now, thanks! I've edited your question to add some helpful hints how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and other formatting options, and to try to distill the essence of your question. Can you take a look and possibly either choose an alternative or combine options to shorten it back down?

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape considering the possibility that you might be a close-voter, would the edit make the question more obvious to you?

Comment: @uhoh I did not vote to close. And yes, I think the edit does make the question more obvious. Particularly that in-line image of Lambert, it's very useful.

Comment: @BenoitLebeaupin I'm guessing that you are asking about an analytical solution (analogous to Lambert's work) rather than simply a search or numerical iteration?

Comment: The answer is "yes". One can change the input parameters and output parameters as long as you have six degrees of freedom. Lambert is usually solved through iterations but there's at least one way to linearize small variations in the solution (full disclosure: I'm currently working on a flight software implementation of small corrections of Lambert solutions). I hope to answer this question in a few days, ping me if I forget by Sunday!

Comment: @ChrisR ping! :-)

Comment: Thanks! So, I just reached out to my boss and friend who will know the answer better than me. It seems intuitive that it can be solved (it's mostly a matter of ellipses and Kepler's laws), but I haven't yet found the way to do it neither in my notes nor in my previous work. So I'm confused for now. In the meantime, the following reference is what I used to code up my Lambert solver: http://ccar.colorado.edu/imd/2015/documents/LambertHandout.pdf .